# How to define a copyable struct containing a String?

Tags: rust

I have a struct like that

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
enum Command {
    Quit,
    Error { msg: String },
}
```

The compiler complains that it cannot generate a copy constructor for `Error`.

I need to make the struct copyable to pass over a channel to another thread.

```
error: the trait `Copy` may not be implemented for this type; variant `Error` does not implement `Copy` [E0205]
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: in this expansion of #[derive_Copy] (defined in src/main.rs)
```

It compiles if `msg` is an `i32`. It looks strange that such basic 
type as `String` is not copyable.

Comment: `String` is not `Copy`able the same way that `Vec` isn't. Both handle heap-allocated content, and so cannot be safely copied with `memcpy`. Relevant page from the book: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/strings.html

Comment: I see but I need to pass object to the channel and it requires types to be copyable. I read this tutorial from cover to cover, but it's to shallow.

Comment: @DaneelS.Yaitskov Types do *not* have to be copyable to be passed through a channel.

Comment: Indeed, only the [`Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Send.html) trait should be needed, which is automatically derived by the compiler and does not imply `Copy`. You should seriously find out where the real problem is. Please show us more code and rephrase the question accordingly.

Answer (score 41):

> For me looks strange that such basic type as string is not copyable.

Rust is *explicit* first.

One of the oft heard complains from C programmers (and most notably Linus Torvald) with regard to C++ is that there is too much implicit copying in C++, which hides memory allocation. Coupled with implicit conversions, they can really creep in the most unexpected places.

Rust instead is designed with an intent to expose the complexity of the underlying operations. It does implicitly perform some conversions (borrowing, from `&T` to `&Trait`), but those are *cheap* (and generally constant time).

This explicitness shows in the two traits you have here:

- `Clone` is about indicating *how* to create a new instance, and must be called explicitly. Most types (but not all) can be copied using it.
- `Copy` is a specific compiler trait which indicates that the developer wishes to activate implicit copying for the type; it is only available if a shallow copy is equivalent to a deep copy, which ensures that no memory allocation will occur as part of those implicit copies

So, to ensure your remark:

- `String` is copyable, use `.clone()`
- `String` is not implicitly copyable, because that would cause non-obvious memory allocations to occur

Answer (score 10):

`String` is, effectively, a pointer to some heap allocated data, it's length and capacity. Copying that information would create two owned variables, both pointing to the same heap allocated data, which would break Rust's memory management (you would run into use-after-free issues).

That said, your struct doesn't need to implement `Copy` to be sent over channels, it just needs to be `Sized`, which `String` is (because the size of a pointer is known to the compiler). Sending a struct or enum with a `String` in it should work out of the box without having to derive any traits.