# Rust Vector Mapping with Strings

Tags: rust

I have to structs with fields of type `String` that I want to map to each other.

```
struct A {
  name: String,
}
struct B {
  id: String
}
     
let a_list = vec![A {name: "a1".to_string()}, A {name: "a2".to_string()}];
    
let b_list = a_list.iter().map(|a| B {id: a.name}).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

When I execute this, I get the following error because of missing `Copy` traits for the field of type `String`.

```
14 |     let b_list = a_list.iter().map(|a| B {id: a.name}).collect::<Vec<_>>();
   |                                               ^^^^^^ move occurs because `a.name` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

My current workaround to this issue is that in the mapping, I temporarily convert the field of type `String` into `&str` and then back again to `String`, which appears kind of hacky to me:

```
let b_list = a_list.iter().map(|a| B {id: a.name.as_str().to_string()}).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

I wonder if there is a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: You want `a.name.clone()`, which does the same thing as your `.as_str().to_string()` but more clearly shows the intent.

Comment: Use Clone. IIt's well explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38305901/11998029

Comment: I'll also add that in this example you can just use `into_iter()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on wether you still need `a_list` after the conversion you could either:

```rust
// if you still need a_list
let b_list: Vec<B> = a_list.iter().map(|a| B{id: a.name.clone()}).collect();
// if you don't need a_list anymore
let b_list: Vec<B> = a_list.into_iter().map(|a| B{id: a.name}).collect();
```